# when i build Android kernel of msm of android-msm-wahoo-4.4-pie-r2 for pixel 2 xl , make failed

Tags: android, linux-kernel

For build the kernel, I use the commands below:

```
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=aarch64-linux-android-
PATH=/home/shallin/android9_r22/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin:$PATH
make wahoo_defconfig
```

But when I run `make`, it shows following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clSxR.jpg)

How to fix that?

Comment: It is a **rule** of Stack Overflow to have error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as *image*. Please, [edit] you question and paste *textual* representation of the error into it. After pasting, you may format error message as a code, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: Please indicate the source of the guidance you are following in thinking that these are the complete and correct commands and appropriate compiler to use.  Also indicate the exact codebase you are building - is it a release tag?